# Issues with while activity while working on sequential workflow using visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint

Am working on sequential work flow using visual studio 2010. An office task has been defined in while loop.After while loop I defined an IfElse activity in which I defined an other while activity. Am trying to debug the application but it doesn't hit the if else activity which is defined after first while loop. Am not sure what the issue might be.

Comment: It's highly probably that your first while loop is not ending. Try to debug the first while loop.

Comment: Yes, I figured out. Issue was with the while condition. It's working fine now.